# How to replace date year in column

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I've got a table that contains about 10K rows that is organized by date.  I need to update some of the years and have tried a few options.

Is there a way that I can The dates are formatted as 2011-mm-dd and I just want to replace the years.

I've tried the following and without success

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET date=DATE_FORMAT(date,'2014-%m-%d') where date='2013-%m-%d')
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE dbo.TableToUpdate
  SET [Date Column] = DATEADD(YEAR, +1, [Date Column]);
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can update your dates to 2014 like this:*

Try **DATE_ADD**

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET date = DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 365 DAY) WHERE YEAR(date) = '2013'
```

and also try **DATE_SUB**

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET date = DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 365 DAY) WHERE YEAR(date) = '2015'
```

Comment: These execute with no errors but no rows effected either.  hmmm

Comment: sorry, my fault. i edit the queries in where clause. try again